# 502 Bad Gateway After Fresh Laravel 7 Project LEMP

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, nginx

I followed the tutorial correctly but in my local machine is receiving a 502 bad gateway. I am using Linux while on the tutorial is using windows 10.

I am not sure why it's not working on mine. I've been using LAMP stack from the start and now I am planning to migrate to Dockerized LEMP stack.

After I open the localhost:8080, I am receiving the 502 bad gateway.

Here's the screenshot of the error 502 bad gateway:
[502-bad-gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYmA8.png)

Here's my config/nginx/conf.d/app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param CRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: tomw1808/laravelproject
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Nginx
    image: tomw1808/nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Here's my Dockerfile_Nginx

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./config/nginx/conf.d/app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
COPY . /var/www
```

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update && apk add \
    build-base \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install Redis Extension
RUN apk add autoconf && pecl install -o -f redis \
&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&&  docker-php-ext-enable redis && apk del autoconf

# Copy config
COPY ./config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www

USER www

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./start_script.sh"]

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ./start_script.sh
```

Thank you! I've been searching how to solve this error unfortunately cannot solve this error.

The expected output should be the Welcome Page Of Fresh Laravel App

Comment: If the server is listening on 80 `listen 80;` why are you trying to load it using `:8080`

Comment: I am not sure but this is what I think. I am accessing the port :8080 on the browser, but on the container side it is forwarded to port 80 then the server is listening also to port 80. Please enlighten me, sorry for my bad english

Comment: First try to find out whether the docker containers are up. from the directory where `docker-compose.yml` file is, run `docker-compose ps` and check that both services are running. if not, then try to get the log from the failing service by running `docker-compose logs`.